# Manipulate markers in Google Maps Javascript API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am really struggling with the structure of the new Google Maps Javascript API.

In the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map) for adding a map with a marker, the new structure wants to `async` load the library, to load the relevant class(es):

```js
  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
  const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
```

OK, so I wrap this in some sort of `async` method to init the map

```js
const initMap = async () => {
  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
  const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
  // ...
}
```

No problem.. but what happens if I want another method to add or manipulate a marker? Do I call `importLibrary` *again*?

```js
const addMarker = async (blah) => {
  // Will this hit some sort of local cache of types??
  const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
  // ...
}
```

I mean.. is this thing cached, or is it going to try to import code from the interweb every time? Why do I have to `async` load just to get a class definition?

There is no top-level `await` in the browser (yet), so the load of these classes needs to be scoped to a `function`, which means they are not accessible outside that scope, like.. another function.

How are people doing this? The whole structure of this API seems bonkers to me.

What I want to do is something like this:

```js
// This won't work, but this is what I want to do:
const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");

class GoogleMap {

  constructor() {
    this._map;
    this._markers = [];
  }

  init(elem) {
    this._map = new Map(elem, {...});
  }

  addMarker(position) {
    this._markers.push(new AdvancedMarkerElement({
      this._map,
      position: position,
    }));
  }
}
```

What is the best-practice guidance for using this [bonkers] API in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Admittedly, the new Marker API is a bit dorky.

Still, the dynamic loading scripts are indeed cached. You can verify this by checking the Network tab and looking for `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/.../marker.js`:

```js
const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
let AdvancedMarkerElement;
({ AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker"));

// some logic 

({ AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker"));
({ AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker"));
```

Secondly, by calling `.importLibrary()`, you're accessing the global `google.maps` namespace. Calling `importLibrary("marker")` then populates the `google.maps.marker` library. That's all there's to it.

Once loaded, these two calls are equivalent:

```js
const m1 = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement(...);
const m2 = new AdvancedMarkerElement(...);
```

That said, you can write your own utility that wraps around the `google.maps.marker` library to avoid the verbose dot paths…

And this brings me to an official utility package ([`@googlemaps/adv-markers-utils`](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-adv-markers-utils)) that's poised to "simplify common patterns for using Advanced Markers."

With it, you only import the `marker` library once (but it's got to be in an async context):

```js
async function main() {
  const {Map} = await google.maps.importLibrary('maps');
  
  // Notice that we don't care about the return value of this statement -- it only populates `google.maps.marker`
  await google.maps.importLibrary('marker');
}
```

Afterwards, you are free to use the synchronous initializer throughout your app:

```js
const marker = new Marker({
  position: {lat: 53.5, lng: 10.05},
  map
});
```

Do check out the [related playground](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-adv-markers-utils/playground/) too.

Comment: Glad to help! If you’re new to gmaps, check out my book too 

Comment: "Admittedly, the new Marker API is a bit dorky." Your'e a lot more polite than I am about that.